# Implementing Email-Only OAuth Login with DRF, NextJS, and Simple JWT

Tags: python, next.js, django-rest-framework, oauth, jwt

I am currently working on a project using Django Rest Framework (DRF) and NextJS and handling user authentication using Simple JWT.

Now, I'm trying to implement OAuth authentication, specifically a mechanism that allows users to log in using only their email, without a password.

Here are the existing classes/views:

```py
class TeacherLoginView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        try:
            user = authenticate(
                request=request,
                email=request.data["email"],
                password=request.data["password"],
            )

            if user != None:
                if not user.is_teacher:
                    return Response(
                        {"is_teacher": "재원생은 {URL}을 통해서 로그인 바랍니다."},
                        status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                    )
                if not user.is_active:
                    return Response(
                        {"is_active": "미승인된 계정입니다. 관리자에게 문의하세요."},
                        status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                    )
                if not ip_check(request, user):
                    return Response(
                        {"error": "학원 외부에서 접속은 불가합니다. 관리자에게 문의하세요."},
                        status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
                    )

            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

            if user:
                user.last_login = timezone.now()
                user.save()

        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class TeacherKakaoLoginVeiw(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            code = request.data.get("code")
            access_token = requests.post(
                '''skip'''
            )
            access_token = access_token.json().get("access_token")

            user_data = requests.get(
                '''skip'''
            )
            user_data = user_data.json()
            kakao_account = user_data.get("kakao_account")
            profile = kakao_account.get("profile")
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=kakao_account.get("email"))
                TeacherLoginView.post(request, user) # this line is the problem 
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create(
                    email=kakao_account.get("email"),
                    username=profile.get("nickname"),
                    oauth="kakao",
                    is_teacher = True,
                    is_active = False,
                )
                user.set_unusable_password()  
                user.save()
                TeacherLoginView.post(request, user) # this line is the problem 
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The TeacherLoginView is an API view that is already implemented and working for regular JWT authentication.

Meanwhile, TeacherKakaoLoginView is a newly-created API view intended for handling Kakao OAuth authentication.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Allow users to log in using only their email address through OAuth (Kakao)
Ensure that logged-in users are also issued JWT tokens
I've scoured the DRF documentation and various forums but haven't found a concrete example that matches what I'm trying to do. I'm a bit lost on how to proceed, especially concerning the following points:

How to adapt the existing TeacherLoginView to work with email-only OAuth login
What changes are necessary in TeacherKakaoLoginView to implement the desired OAuth functionality and issue JWT tokens upon successful authentication
Any pointers, suggestions, or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify TeacherKakaoLoginView to:

```
   class TeacherKakaoLoginView(APIView):
       permission_classes = [AllowAny]

       def post(self, request):
           try:
               # OAuth code


               email = kakao_account.get("email")
               try:
                   user = User.objects.get(email=email)
               except User.DoesNotExist:
                   user = User.objects.create(
                       email=email,
                       username=profile.get("nickname"),
                       oauth="kakao",
                       is_teacher=True,
                       is_active=False,
                   )
                   user.set_unusable_password()
                   user.save()

               # Issue JWT tokens
               refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
               return Response({
                   'refresh': str(refresh),
                   'access': str(refresh.access_token),
               })

           except Exception:
               return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: "Can I directly use the part(check user.is_teacher, is acctive, ip_check) from TeacherLoginView in TeacherKakaoLoginView, or do I have to repeat the same section in TeacherKakaoLoginView?"